# Noisy PAS pump on Honda crv

Tags: honda

Honda CR-V pas pump very noisy when starting from cold, loud clicking noise,but quieter when warm also a grinding noise when engine turned off.
The belt seems very tight, how much deflection should it have.
Suggestions on cause and cure appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the belt off and checking the pump by hand, there will probably be a tensioner that you can check as well.

All components should be easy to rotate and not noisy or grinding.

Comment: Thanks Dufferson, I'll give it a go and let you know 